# MSET in StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

Is there a method for to carry out `MSET` in Redis from StackExchange.Redis.

After referring [documentation](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers), the below code I wrote is carrying out `StringSetAsync` to add multiple key-value pairs in Redis. Do we have something like `IDatabase.StringSet(RedisKey[], RedisValue[])` ?

```
  public void Add(IEnumerable<CacheKeyValue> cacheKeyValues)
  {
      var tasks = new List<Task>();

      foreach(var kv in cacheKeyValues.ToList())
      {
          tasks.Add(((Task<bool>)DB.StringSetAsync(kv.Key, ((RedisValue)kv.Value))).ContinueWith((b) => kv.Status = true));
      }

      Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to call:

```
bool StringSet(KeyValuePair<RedisKey, RedisValue>[] values, When when = When.Always, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
```

but only passing in the first parameter (this will mean the second and third parameters are the defaults, which means you will get `MSET` behaviour).

as per https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/c4c9c1fdb455070415e82d2f104fc89a90b057b5/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/IDatabase.cs :

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets the given keys to their respective values. If "not exists" is specified, this will not perform any operation at all even if just a single key already exists.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>True if the keys were set, else False</returns>
/// <remarks>http://redis.io/commands/mset</remarks>
/// <remarks>http://redis.io/commands/msetnx</remarks>
bool StringSet(KeyValuePair<RedisKey, RedisValue>[] values, When when = When.Always, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
```

There is also an `async` equivalent:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets the given keys to their respective values. If "not exists" is specified, this will not perform any operation at all even if just a single key already exists.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>True if the keys were set, else False</returns>
/// <remarks>http://redis.io/commands/mset</remarks>
/// <remarks>http://redis.io/commands/msetnx</remarks>
Task<bool> StringSetAsync(KeyValuePair<RedisKey, RedisValue>[] values, When when = When.Always, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
```

Comment: this looks good. I will test it and mark it as answer. Do we have something similar for adding multiple key-value/s pair to a set ? I think it is not available in redis as well (https://redis.io/commands#set). In that case, I can use pipelining [https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers].

Comment: You are probably best to create a completely new question for that @Brij .